# How do I subset an array in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a recursive merge sort in C that sorts the input taken from stdin in `ARGV`. To do this, I need to create new arrays that are copies of a subset of the `ARGV` array. I need copies because I am then going to use them to modify the original array, which I cannot do in place.

```
void pm_merge(char **A, int p, int q, int r)
{
    char **L;
    char **R; 
    int i;

    L = malloc(sizeof(char*) * pm_stringlen(A) + 1);

    i = 0;
    while (i <= q)
        strncpy(L[i], A[i], pm_stringlen(A[i]));
}

void pm_mergesort(char **A, int p, int r)
{
    int q;
    if (p < r) 
    {
        q = (p + r) / 2;
        pm_mergesort(A, p, q);
        pm_mergesort(A, q + 1, r);
        pm_merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}
```

I've included `pm_mergesort()` for context but the real problems lie in the `pm_merge()` function. Can anyone help me out? The code gives me a set fault although it does compile.

Comment: Why not simply use indexes for your sub-set? One index for the start, one for the end. Or perhaps a start index and a length.

Comment: What is your problem? Doesn't the code compile, doesn't it do the right thing? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have a function `m()` that accepts a pointer and a size, you can call it on a subset by calling things like `m(p + x, size - x)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "input taken from stdin in ARGV" ? Either input from stdin, or from argv or maybe from a file named as commandline parameters...

Comment: 1) I Need to be able to re-order the original array based on the subarrays so I can't re-order in place
2) I get a seg fault
3) same as #1 
4) command line parameters are stored in the array ARGV in main in c